# Creating complex MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, sql-update

I have two tables. First called "TestGroup":

[image]

And second "Test":

[image]

Test belongs to TestGroup (Test.testgroupID is foreign key). I'm trying to create query that will Update Test.authorID based on it's TestGroup's authorID. I mean, query must run every row of Test, find it's TestGroup's authorID and set row's authorID field to this value.

Can't figure out this query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Test T 
INNER JOIN TestGroup TG ON T.testgroupID = TG.id 
SET T.authorID = TG.authorID
```

Comment: He said he wanted a complex query, not something so simple :)